# Better way to get BOOL from ColdFusion boolean return type in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, coldfusion, boolean, nsurlrequest

I have a method in my app which sends a request to the server to check if the user is currently logged in. This ColdFusion function returns type `boolean`. When I `NSLog` the data returned, this is what I get:

`<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><boolean value='true'/></data></wddxPacket>`.

Currently, to determine if it returned true or false I'm searching for a substring 'true' in that returned string. That does not seem like a good solution. My question is, is there a better way to get an Objective-C `BOOL` from this function? If it's better to change the ColdFusion function, I luckily can do that. Thanks!

ColdFusion function:

```
<cffunction name="loggedIn" returnType="Boolean" output="false" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="sessionID" type="UUID" required="true">
    <cfquery name="q_session" datasource="#request.db_dsn#">
        SELECT ...
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn q_session.recordCount gte 1>
</cffunction>
```

Objective-C method snippet:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:myURLVar];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *requestError = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                            returningResponse:&response
                                                        error:&requestError];

    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseData);
    if ([responseData rangeOfString:@"true" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound){
        sessionIsActive = YES;
    }
```

Comment: If you add `returnformat=json` to the URL when you make the request, it will be returned in JSON - which is MUCH easier to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add `returnFormat="plain"` to your `cffunction`.

> > plain: ensure that the return value is a type that ColdFusion can convert directly to a string, and return the string value without serialization. Valid types include all simple types, such as numbers, and XML objects. If the return value is a complex type, such as an array, or a binary value, ColdFusion generates an error. If you specify a returntype attribute, its value must be any, boolean, date, guid, numeric, string, uuid, variablename, or XML; otherwise, ColdFusion generates an error.
>
> By default, ColdFusion serializes all return types (including simple return types), except XML, into WDDX format, and returns XML data as XML text.

That *should* give you just the string, which would be simpler to parse.

[[source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html)]